# Optimize LCP ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, optimization

I make a site using reactjs, I want it to be more Google search friendly. So I optimize the download speed, lcp.....

But I'm having a problem with Total Blocking Time & Largest Contentful Paint. Anyone with experience, please guide me on how to optimize LCP when downloading data from the api.

This is my site: https://coolxgame.com.

I using preload image, but it not reduce Total Blocking Time & Largest Contentful Paint.